A puzzle on Borromean monoids
This question arose first as a question about varieties in the context of universal algebra, but can be rephrased as a fun combinatorial/computational problem about free monoids. The question is the following:
Definition: We call a (non-trivial) monoid with a $0$ element, over a set of generators $S$, subject to some list of equations Borromean if adding any one equation of the form
$$a=b,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are distinct generators, forces the entire monoid to be the trivial monoid $\{0\}$.
i.e. Setting any two generators equal collapses the entire monoid. Here is an example on a set of two generators, $\{f,g\}$. Our equations are:
\begin{align*}
f=  0 \\ 
g = e
\end{align*}
If we now add the equations $f=g$ then we get $e=0$ so $M=\{0\}$.
Which is essentially the answer given by armsa. However, one can also do this for $4$ generators with the following equations,
\begin{align*}
fg &= 0 \\ 
hgfj &= e 
\end{align*}
Proving that this is a Borromean monoid is quite fun. We can then also add one, or both of the equations from the first example to obtain Borromean monoids over $5$ and $6$ generators. But the question is, for which $n$ is there a Borromean monoid over $n$ generators? Particularly, is there a Borromean monoid over $3$ generators?

You should add in the definition that a Borromean monoid should be nontrivial. Now, in your four generators example, it is indeed fun to verify that identifying two generators leads to a trivial monoid, but how do you show that the original monoid is nontrivial? It does not seem to be that easy. For instance, it has no finite quotient.

Actually it is infinite, as it admits the polycyclic monoid $\langle a\bar a = b\bar b = 1, a\bar b = b\bar a = 0\rangle$ as a quotient.

@J.-E.Pin indeed this condition should be added, I sortof assumed it should be obvious from the context that we would want this, and avoided it for succinctness. My proof that it is not trivial was carried out on the unary-algebra side (see linked question) where one can choose $f,g,h,j$ to have some combination of surjective, injective, not injective and not surjective, as properties, and then one needs at least an infinite underlying set, to allow functions which are surjective but not injective for example. I am not sure I understand your explanation however.

With your notation, a presentation of the polycyclic monoid would be $\langle hg = fj = e, hj = fg = 0\rangle$. This monoid, which is clearly a quotient of yours, is known to be infinite.

@J.-E.Pin After reading up on the polycyclic monoids, it would seem that they are all Borromean, answering the question for the even integers, for odd integers, one can simply add one more generator and identify it with $0$. This however doesn't solve the case of $n=3$!

Good point, I agree. For $n = 3$, the answer might be negative, but difficult to prove!

Maybe you can post a more detailed proof why even integers are "done"?

@MartinBrandenburg thank you for the suggestion, I have done so. I would appreciate critique on my phrasing/terminology, as for example the wording "set these two generators equal" doesn't seem quite right.

What you actually mean that the quotient of your monoid by the (congruence relation generated by) relation a=b is trivial. But I think that's understood.

It is impossible for $n \geq 3$ when $M$ is commutative. Proof: for any commutative monoid, we can establish a divisibility preorder whose sense of equality is compatible with the monoid operation. Further, an absorption monoid is trivial iff $0 = 1$ according to the preorder. Because we have $1$ as the bottom and $0$ as the top of the preorder, the only way to trivialize the monoid is to set a 0-divisor and a unit equal. Impossibility follows from the pigeonhole principle.

This also explains why the working answers rely on weird aspects of non-commutativity such as one-sided inverses: they must, or else we cannot break free of the preorder's iron fist. (Note that the preorder is still defined on any monoid but its sense of equality won't be compatible with the monoid operation.)

As per request, here is a proof that for each natural number $n$, there is a Borromean monoid over $2n$ generators. Let the generators be
$$\{a_1, \overline{a_1}, ..., a_n,\overline{a_n}\}$$
and for each $i,j$ such that $i\neq j$ quotient by the equations
$$a_i\overline{a_i} = e$$
and
$$a_i\overline{a_j}= 0$$
This is the polycyclic monoid over $n$ generators. We proceed by cases:
Suppose we set $a_i=a_j$ where $i\neq j$, then
$$e = a_i\overline{a_i} = a_j\overline{a_i} = 0$$
Hence the monoid is trivial. Now suppose we set $a_i=\overline{a_j}$ where $i\neq j$ then $a_i^2 = 0$ so
$$0 = a_i^2\overline{a_i}^2 = e$$
Hence the monoid is trivial.
Suppose we set $a_i=\overline{a_i}$, then $a_i^2 = e$ then for some $j\neq i$ we have
$$e = a_j(a_i^2)\overline{a_j} = a_ja_i(a_i\overline{a_j}) = 0$$
Hence the monoid is trivial.
Finally suppose we set $\overline{a_i}=\overline{a_j}$ for some $i\neq j$. Then
$$e= a_i\overline{a_i}=a_i\overline{a_j}=0$$
Hence the monoid is trivial. So setting any two distinct generators equal forces the monoid to be trivial. Note that I am assuming that the polycyclic monoid is itself non-trivial. Note that nowhere in our proof did we use the fact that the generating set was finite, so we can in fact do this for generating sets of arbitrary non finite cardinalities as well.

Here is the $n = 3$ solution:
$$
xy = e \\
xzy = 0 \\
z^2 = e
$$
I will prove it's nontrivial by concretely realizing these generators as pointed set endofunctions on $(\mathbb{N}, 0)$:
$$
y: n \mapsto 2n \\
x: n \mapsto \begin{cases}
n/2 \text{ if } 2 \mid n\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
z: n \mapsto \begin{cases}
n-1 \text{ if } 2 \mid n\\
n+1 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
One can verify $x, y, z$ have the relations desired and have the Borromean property, as desired.

Nice! thanks. Another one that I recently found was $cba=e$ and $cab= 0$ and what is interesting is that these two share a common trait, which is that all the words which we set to $0$ or $e$ are non overlapping. This allows one to prove non-triviality as well, since if there were a deduction that $e=0$ from the equations, then it is necessarily a series of substitutions, which can be reconstructed as a simplification of one word in two ways, yielding $e$ and $0$ respectively, but since our equations have non overlapping terms, simplification is unique, hence this is not possible
